# Move element created in function while manipulate existing page

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-manipulation

I'm trying to move an existing element from oneplace in the DOM to another. I'm using a plugin for chrome "User Javascript and CSS" and the page I'm manipulate is https://www.kappahl.com/sv-SE/rea/herr/rea/?

I want to move the span element "product-card__percent--sale" below "grid-item__image-spacer". But nothing happens down in the grid with ID #Productlist. And as told, now I'm going crazy.

I know it's created in a function and I have to check if the function is done before calling the elements.
So far I have come to this point [Top line is fine but not the rest of the products](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUVNw.jpg). 
The result should be that in the bottom right corner of each image of the products would have the "50%" "sign".

I have search through every space from google to youtube but I can't understand what I'm doing wrong.

I know that just create a variabel won't work and I thought ready function would work. I also tried with length etc.

**I have tried following:**

```
let a = $(".product-card__percent--sale");

let b = $(".grid-item__image-spacer");

a.insertAfter(b);
```

**And:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 if($(".product-card__percent--sale").insertAfter($("header .grid-item__image-spacer")));

    });
```

**This is how my code look like a the moment**

JS

```
$(".product-card__wrapper").each(function () {
  var newprice = $(this).find('.product-card__percent--sale');
   $(this).find('.grid-item__image-spacer').parent().after(newprice );
});
```

CSS:

```
/*Override the old grid*/
#ProductList {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 25%);
    grid-gap: 18.5px;
}

/*Create sale-percent look*/
.product-card__percent--sale {
    color: white;
    background-color: #ee324c;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 65px;
    width: 65px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
   /* display:inline-block;*/
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 20px 5px 5px 10px;
}
```

It's hard to show the code when I'm just editing an existing page. Sorry for that but if someone could help me out it would just be beautiful! :)

Comment: Please read [ask]. Format your question a bit so that it improves the readability

Comment: I think a made it a little bit easier to read now. My first first question so it can just get better from here.

Comment: well did you debug and see if it is finding the elements? My guess is it is dynamically loaded and element are not there. A simple `console.log(a.length, b.length)` would show that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: As per the comment and the updated code in your post, the code below might fit your need.

```
$(function(){
    setInterval(function() {
        $(".product-card__percent--sale").each(function(){
            $(this).closest(".product-card")
                .find(".grid-item__image-spacer")
                .append($(this));
        });
    }, 200);
})
```

or

```
$(function(){
    setInterval(function() {
        $(".product-card__wrapper").each(function () {
            var newprice = $(this).find('.product-card__percent--sale');
            $(this).find('.grid-item__image-spacer')
                .parent().after(newprice );
        });
    }, 200);
})
```

both should work.

And here's the CSS

```
/*Override the old grid*/
#ProductList {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 25%);
    grid-gap: 18.5px;
}

/*Create sale-percent look*/
.product-card__percent--sale {
    color: white;
    background-color: #ee324c;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 65px;
    width: 65px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
   /* display:inline-block;*/
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 20px 5px 5px 10px;
}

.grid-item__image-spacer{
    position: relative;
}
.product-card__percent--sale{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

---

---

---

You have to run the code after the dom elements are created and

```
let a = $(".product-card__percent--sale");
let b = $(".grid-item__image-spacer");
a.insertAfter(b);
```

would insert all the numbers to all the images, so it could be

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $(".product-card__percent--sale").each(function(){
        $(this).closest(".product-card__bottom--wrapper")
            .find(".product-card__infoicons").prepend($(this));
    });
}, 10);
```

or

```
setInterval(function() {
    $(".product-card__percent--sale").each(function(){
        $(this).closest(".product-card__bottom--wrapper").find(".product-card__infoicons").prepend($(this));
    });
}, 200);
```

And you'll need these to set the position

```
.product-card__percent--sale{
    line-height: 25px;
    left: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Glad you liked it! :) I think it's really awesome too.

And you´re suggestion almost made the thing but it still not accessing the .product-card__percent--sale below. It only append to the topline. So close now!

Comment: I thought you'd like it to display at the bottom right of the picture as soon as I saw `the bottom right corner of each image`, anyway I edited the code but it still needs to be improved as you can see the star sign is covered by the number.

Comment: Sorry for being so bad at explain. The first code did exactly what I wanted just that it only append the change on the top row. Not down where all the products is showing, right under the navbar and beside the sidebar.

Comment: Cause those products are dynamically created once a user scrolls down the page but the code only fires once after the page is loaded. One way is to execute the code with `setInterval`, but it's just a workaround, not a perfect solution. I'll add it into the post.

Comment: Did it work for you? If you tried it out? For me it did the same as the other one and I tried modified it but still doing nothing. I know this was a hard nut to crack =(

Comment: [This is what I see.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gfu4U.jpg) , maybe there's something wrong with your code or I probably misunderstand again. (not a native English speaker)

Comment: [link](https://i.imgur.com/5BkmX8V.jpg) This is how it´s look for me. Topline is fine just som styling left but after i everything exactly as it was before. (I'm not so good to write in English either)

Comment: Would you please provide the JS and CSS that are using in the picture you post above? And, it seems you'd like them to display at the top right of each picture?

Comment: I have updated the question with code that looks most as the result I want. [Updated picture with newest code](https://i.imgur.com/XH7NBr7.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

so as you say you need to show the element below Pictures.

```
$(".product-card__wrapper").each(function () {
  var newprice = $(this).find('.product-card__percent--sale');
   $(this).find('.grid-item__image-spacer').parent().after(newprice );
});
```

First of all, get your all elements on your needs. then include what elements do you want to change(new price). then you can change them. I don't have the source to try it but I think it will be work fine. If it's not working try with .parent() to see what element jquery get.I hope it helps

Comment: It did exactly what I wanted in the top row, but it still not accessing the other products who are dynamically created under the navbar. 
My issue is the same, I don't have the source either just the homepage and the inspector and then I use the plugin for chrome that I mentioned in the question.

Comment: @LittleStarJenny  do you mean REAFAVORITER part? Yes, you cant change them cause the class is different below the navbar. if you want the function works for all of them add a custom class to them and again if you can't change the main code change your selectors,I think all of them are in article .

Comment: $("article").each(function () {